# Show modal content from another page within same pages popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Similar questions like this has been posted before but none solved my issue. I'm trying to get enrollments.php page to show as a modal popup within index.php page

**index.php**

```
<button class="sess_btn sess_btn1" id="btn_enrol">Enrollments</button>  
<div id="enrolModal"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //button modal
    $('#btn_enrol').click(function(){
        //using ajax post
        $.post('enrollments.php',function() {
            $('#enrolModal').html(); //Fill DIV enrolModal with enrollments.php content
        })
    //Calling Modal
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    })
})
//-------------
</script>
```

**enrollments.php**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also, when I try to click on the button several times there are quick blinks on the browser window. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Using `$.post` callback incorrectly and using `html()` incorrectly. Start in the API docs  [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) .... [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) and look at examples

Comment: In addition, read up on async nature of AJAX requests - make sure you wait for the result to arrive before you try to manipulate the DOM (turn it into a modal).

Comment: Close but not exactly what I'm in search for, some code example would have been quite helpful as I'm a newby with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, I got it done a little differently. Instead of a button I used a link as shown.

**index.html**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {              
        $('.li-modal').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        })
    });
</script>

    <a href="enrollments.php" class="li-modal" id="enrol_link" onMouseOver="this.style.background='rgb(0,66,79)'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='#4CAF50'">Enrollments</a>

    <div class="modal fade text-center" id="theModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**enrollments.php**

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('theModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    window.location.href = "updatesession.php";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        window.location.href = "updatesession.php";
    }
}
</script>

    <div id="model-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
          <p>Session Editor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Select Session: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <p>Modal Footer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you use a code playground to explain how your code worked 

Currently the answer is marked as correct by you and was also asked by you.

Answer (score 0):

Did the corrections in code to use the jquery API correctly. Not tested but, below code will work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //button modal
    $('#btn_enrol').click(function(){

        $.post( "enrollments.php", function( htmlContents ) {
          $('#enrolModal').html( htmlContents ); 

          //Show the Modal once you get enrollments.php html contents
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });      
    })
})
//-------------
</script>
```